# Matching % in a path

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

How can I make target match like this:

```
efl_class_bundles = \                                                         
  efl_class_returnszero \                                                     
  efl_class_cmd_regcmp \                                                      
  efl_class_expression                                                        

.PHONY: $(efl_class_bundles)                                                  
$(efl_class_bundles): version syntax \                                        
  test/$@/efl_main.json \                                                     
  test/$@/01_$@.json \                                                        
  test/$@/02_efl_test_simple.json                                             
   prove t/efl_class_$@_csv.t                                                 
   prove t/efl_class_$@_json.t                                                

test/%/efl_main.json: test/%/efl_main.csv                                     
   $(CSVTOJSON) -b efl_main < $< > $@                                         
   perl -pi -e 's/csv/json/' $@
```

When I attempt 'make efl_class_returnszero' I get the following error, which suggests to me that the prerequisite test/$@/efl_main.json cannot match the target 'test/%/efl_main.json' Han can I make this work?

```
prove t/00_version.t
t/00_version.t .. ok   
All tests successful.
Files=1, Tests=1,  0 wallclock secs ( 0.03 usr  0.00 sys 
Result: PASS
prove t/01_syntax.t
t/01_syntax.t .. ok   
All tests successful.
Files=1, Tests=1,  0 wallclock secs ( 0.02 usr  0.00 sys 
Result: PASS
make: *** No rule to make target 'test//efl_main.json', needed by
  'efl_class_returnszero'.  Stop.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use automatic variables like `$@` in a prerequisites list.  They are normally only available in the recipe.  See [automatic variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html) in the manual.

You can enable [secondary expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Secondary-Expansion.html), if you want; your rule would then look like this:

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:
(efl_class_bundles): version syntax \
                     test/$$@/efl_main.json \
                     test/$$@/01_$$@.json \
                     test/$$@/02_efl_test_simple.json
        prove t/efl_class_$@_csv.t
        prove t/efl_class_$@_json.t
```